# How to Configure Events List in Wordpress to Erase Event Once Date is Past

Tags: php, events, wordpress, sorting

I currently have some code setup to display upcoming events set by the admin based on the date of the event.  The upcoming events are sorted by the next upcoming event, starting from the top, and then going down. I've limited it to just two.

But, when the start of the day comes (e.g. midnight of event date), the event disappears.  **I'd like the event to still show through midnight of the next day (e.g. the start of the next day).**  Right now, the event is disappearing the second that the day of the event comes...

Does anyone know how to change this with the current code that I have?

```
<div class="boxer events">
<h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
<?php
//The Query
query_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'meta_key' => 'event_date',
'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
'meta_compare' => '>',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
));

//The Loop
$count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++;
//The Title
$title = $post->post_title;
$event_datee = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
?>
<dl>
<dt><a title="<?php echo $title; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></dt>
<div class="postdate">
<div class="month m-<?php $dtes = get('event_date'); $timestamp = strtotime($dtes); echo date('n', $timestamp); //month ?>"></div>
<div class="day d-<?php $dtes = get('event_date'); $timestamp = strtotime($dtes); echo date('d', $timestamp); //day ?>"></div>
<div class="year y-<?php $dtes = get('event_date'); $timestamp = strtotime($dtes); echo date('Y', $timestamp); //year ?>"></div>
</div>
<dd><?php the_excerpt(); ?></dd>
</dl>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--end boxerevents-->
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This **isn't** a vote-to-close, but you might find the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) a useful resource for WP questions.

Comment: This code does not show any deletions, are you sure this is the correct code that deals with cleaning up events?  Is this a plugin that you are trying to customize?

Comment: The events do disappear once midnight of the event date comes... I am using Flutter to set up new events.  But this piece of code is simply in the index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison for the query is looking at the date from today `date('Y-m-d')`

Instead you can tell it to use tomorrow as it to get things happening today using yesterdays date. Try substituting the `date(...)` with `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'))`

Note: I think you need to use -1 here but it might need +1 instead.

I also think you might be able to just swap the `'meta_compare' => '>',` for `'meta_compare' => '>=',` *notice the **>** changed to **>=*** in which case you would just leave the `date(...)` part as it is but this depends on how this plugin stores dates.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  You rock, Richard!

Comment: Actually, it did not quite do it.  I was testing locally, and I got a different result when I uploaded it to the remote server.  You can see it in the middle column underneath the heading Upcoming Events.  As you can see, it's pulling up yesterday's event on the 18th, which I want to have disappeared by midnight last night, the start of the 19th.  Does that make sense?  Is there any way to change that?  That's what I really need changed...

Comment: Nevermind... got it.  One little thing had to be changed. Instead of having >=, I needed to keep it at >.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, The >= was only intended as an 'alternative' to changing the date(...) as you have discovered. Also in relation to the other comments posted to your question. This will not delete the actual events, it simply avoids fetching them in the query. If you want to delete them as well you would need to do something different. However, in your question you suggested the current solution was 'partially working' so assumed you just don't want to fetch them

Answer (score 0):

My **best guess** from your code is this is the area:

```
<?php
//The Query
query_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'meta_key' => 'event_date',
'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
'meta_compare' => '>',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

It looks like it fetches the events (not really deleting them) and therefore it DOES NOT get you old events only the current `date('Y-m-d')` and onwards.

But again this is an educated guess having no background in this 'event' / plugin.

Comment: Yeah, the events just disappear once midnight of the day of the event comes.  I'd like to find some code to extend it for the duration of the day of the event to midnight of the next day.  So, if the event is on December 24th, I'd like the event to stay there until 12am, December 25th.  Does that make sense?